# How to invoke android app from Xamarin Android app

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am developing eCommerce app using Xamarin Android, I want to invoke native app ask from Xamarin Android app.

Example: In android apps we use build.gradle file to add dependency app sdks.

How can I invoke native app skd in Xamarin Android app.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I invoke native app sdk in Xamarin Android app.

There are two ways to bind a Java Library into your `Xamarin.Android` app:

1. Use JNI to bind a native library. You can refer to [Working with JNI](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/working_with_jni/).
2. Create a binding library that wraps the Java Library, by this way you can refer to the following documentations:

   [Binding a .JAR](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/)

   [Binding an .AAR](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/)

   [Binding an Eclipse Library Project](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-library-project/)